# What do you use to capture webpages, diagram/pictures and code snippets for later reference?

Tags: code-snippets

What do you use to capture webpages, diagram/pictures and code snippets for later reference?

Comment: Keep in mind, most of the Firefox webpage capture extensions have limits.  If a webpage goes down a long way, not all of it will be captured to an image.  I think this is a FF limitation.  I know that the paid version of Page Saver has an option to select portions to save.

Answer (score 7):

Evernote http://www.evernote.com and delicious http://www.delicious.com

Answer (score 3):

- [Evernote](http://evernote.com/)
- [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)'s clipboard feature (*Notepad2.exe /c* as a link in [Launchy](http://launchy.net/))
- [Windows Clippings](http://www.windowclippings.com/) or [PrintKey](http://www.webtree.ca/newlife/printkey_info.htm)
- Firefox extension [Page Saver](http://pearlcrescent.com/products/pagesaver/)
- [Delicious](http://delicious.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft OneNote.

Answer (score 2):

I find [google notebook](http://www.google.com/notebook) is very good for drive by code snippeting and [google bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks) especially as when used with the google toolbar, for web pages.

The benefit of these tools are that they are available from any pc on the web, though a good use of semantic organisation using labels is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I just have an emacs instance running on my home machine, under screen. Whereever I am (and have network) I can connect to it remotely. I stick all useful urls, birthday present ideas, future dates, code snippets, ideas for docs etcetc in there.

I rarely have doodles/diagrams I need to capture, I tend to draw them in ascii in my file if needed.

I must admit I'm a bit stuck if I have no network/wifi somewhere, but that's rarely the case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer#80842):

The combination of OneNote with a tablet PC is awesome! I was a bit of a skeptic at first. I used the trial version and then forgot about it. A year later I had an unruly collection of files, project related emails, notebooks and scraps of paper all scattered throughout my life. I went back to OneNote and all my problems went away. Some highlights:

- Everything is searchable. The character recognition is good enough that my chicken-scratch meeting notes can be searched. Text within images is searchable.
- OneNote syncs with Outlook so finding meeting notes is a breeze.
- I now embed all files into OneNote - pdfs, spreadsheets, word docs, images, web clippings.
- OneNote is constantly saving all changes so, combined with a scheduled automated backup, everything is in one place and is safe.
- There are some built-in collaboration tools I have yet to try but that look useful.

It is **SO** worth the price. It allows you to get started on a project and avoid all that time spent deciding how to organize things.

Answer (score 1):

[Zotero](http://www.zotero.org), is a nice plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

[SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) 
captures everything you could want, and lets you annotate it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the [good old url](http://del.icio.us) for delicious

Apart from that i use the [Scrapbook extension](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/) in firefox when i want to save something on the disk. It's possible to tag the page, edit it and remove those stupids ads before saving it.

I also have a [Wiki on a stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/) that i carry around on a usbkey for code snippets that should go to other clients when i'm travelling around

Mostly, my code snippets are embedded into projects i carry on the same usb key, which allows me to demonstrate some technologies right off to the client and get his advice based on a demonstration, not a listing of code...

Answer (score 0):

For screen shots, I use a mix between ScrapBook and ScreenGrab.  They are both firefox plugins that are pretty amazing when you need to get a screenshot of a page for editing.  Works great for consulting.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146

Answer (score 0):

[Delicious Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615) extension for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It's a little primitive, but I've been using tiddlywiki (self-contained, single-file wiki) http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ which works good for basic text and markup. I combine it with a plugin to sync it with Outlook's notes (http://syncoutlooknotes.tiddlyspot.com/#SyncOutlookNotes) so that I can then sync it to my blackberry using the standard outlook-blackberry sync mechanism. This has the significant advantage that I can look at my notes and even write new notes when I'm out and about, away from my laptop, or just don't feel like lugging the laptop around to a meeting that I don't really need it for.

I'd prefer using something more advanced like Onenote, but being able to take my notes with my in the little blackberry has turned out to be a significant advantage.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Notebook](http://www.google.com/notebook/) is very convenient tool. You can clip and save any parts of web pages without leaving your browser tab. The Notebook plug-in automatically saves them as separate notes in your notebooks and keep the links back to the original web pages. You can organize your clippings later by moving them between your notebooks and/or tagging them. Very good for code snippets and references.